# How to use BAC0 to set weekly schedule

Tags: python, schedule, bacnet

I'm try to set a device's weekly schedule by using python's BAC0 library. But I can't find any example from BAC0 Documentation. The object identifier is "Schedule:2". For example I want to implement following functions:
* add an event "Occupied 01:00 to 02:00" to Monday
* delete last event from Monday
* change first event's start time of Monday to 01:15
Can any one give some sample code of these? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now supported, please find documentation here :
https://bac0.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schedules.html?highlight=schedule